# what is the purpose of capacitors in audio amplifiers?

Tags: amplifier

what is the purpose of capacitors in audio amplifiers? Yea, dumb general question but I dont know like for example in this photo what does that huge capacitor do [image]

Comment: In general, capacitors do wildly different things in audio amplifiers, from power supply energy storage to signal coupling and filtering. Unless you can provide a schematic of the device, we can only guess where it is connected and why. My guess is it is power supply bulk reservoir cap.

Comment: They add cost and take up PCB space.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/298683/is-a-minimum-of-1000%C2%B5f-capacitance-needed-between-an-lm386s-output-and-a-speake

Comment: Yes It is smart to learn to use a search engine answers before asking lazy ones. But no such thing as a "dumb question".  Lazy ones maybe. Just keep searching  with smarter key words & search   images too and  youtube videos. If this displeases you ask for help from TCM  Dr.

Comment: If this displeases anyone, may I suggest you ask for help from TCM  Dr.  It took me 50 yrs to find out a treatable health issue , don't wait for someone to figure it out.  Look it up. And keep searching for better positive answers. They are all out there.

Answer (score 0):

The one huge capacitor is several thousand microfarads at 50V is low ESR to bypass from the DC battery  all the high frequency AC current produced by the Amplifier.

The Class D is more efficient than Class AB for high power but uses ultrasonic pulse waves using PWM audio so that the speakers only see current for the audio power signal and not the PWM pulse switched battery voltage at some  40 kHz or so plus all the harmonics from the class D bridged switches.

See schematic and simulation in comment. [image]

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/vcuyyw3   Bode plot

Comment: What are microfarads?

Comment: What is inside it?

Comment: Have you ever tried a search engine?

Comment: This is a better  link simulation https://tinyurl.com/uujpyfm